# Flattening and object with an array of objects in to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a GraphQL endpoint that returns data (called locations) in the following format;

```
[
    {
        "name": "Location 1",
        "description": "-",
        "state": "Georgia",
        "address": "Kennesaw, GA 30144",
        "services": {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id": "cG9zdDo0OQ==",
                    "name": "Window Cleaning",
                    "color": "#00A7E3"
                }
            ]
        },
    },
    {
        "name": "Location 2",
        "description": "-",
        "state": "California",
        "address": "Los Angeles, 90016",
        "services": {
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "id": "cG9zdDo1Mg==",
                    "name": "Large Project Waterproofing",
                    "color": "#00668A"
                },
                {
                    "id": "cG9zdDo1MA==",
                    "name": "Surfaces, Stone & Metal Refinishing",
                    "color": "#333333"
                },
                {
                    "id": "cG9zdDo0OQ==",
                    "name": "Window Cleaning",
                    "color": "#00A7E3"
                }
            ]
        },
    },
]
```

What I would like to do is "flatten" it so that service becomes the array of objects and nodes is no longer there. So the expected result would be;

```
[
    {
        "name": "Location 1",
        "description": "-",
        "state": "Georgia",
        "address": "Kennesaw, GA 30144",
        "services": [
                {
                    "id": "cG9zdDo0OQ==",
                    "name": "Window Cleaning",
                    "color": "#00A7E3"
                }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Location 2",
        "description": "-",
        "state": "California",
        "address": "Los Angeles, 90016",
        "services": [
                {
                    "id": "cG9zdDo1Mg==",
                    "name": "Large Project Waterproofing",
                    "color": "#00668A"
                },
                {
                    "id": "cG9zdDo1MA==",
                    "name": "Surfaces, Stone & Metal Refinishing",
                    "color": "#333333"
                },
                {
                    "id": "cG9zdDo0OQ==",
                    "name": "Window Cleaning",
                    "color": "#00A7E3"
                }
        ]
    },
]
```

I have tried looking at using the array.map method to do this with something like the following;

```
const locations = locations.map((location) =>
    location.services.nodes.map((service) => service)
);
```

Comment: Can you not have your endpoint return the data in the right structure?.

Answer (score 0):

Map the array to a new one where the `services.nodes` array is set into `services`

```js
const newLocations = locations.map(({ services: { nodes }, ...location }) => ({
  ...location,
  services: nodes,
}));
```

```js
const locations = [{"name":"Location 1","description":"-","state":"Georgia","address":"Kennesaw, GA 30144","services":{"nodes":[{"id":"cG9zdDo0OQ==","name":"Window Cleaning","color":"#00A7E3"}]}},{"name":"Location 2","description":"-","state":"California","address":"Los Angeles, 90016","services":{"nodes":[{"id":"cG9zdDo1Mg==","name":"Large Project Waterproofing","color":"#00668A"},{"id":"cG9zdDo1MA==","name":"Surfaces, Stone & Metal Refinishing","color":"#333333"},{"id":"cG9zdDo0OQ==","name":"Window Cleaning","color":"#00A7E3"}]}}];

const newLocations = locations.map(({ services: { nodes }, ...location }) => ({
  ...location,
  services: nodes,
}));

console.log(newLocations);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: 10 seconds faster :)